# Derivative of rotating unit vector in coordinate free maner

Tags: vectors, physics, vector-analysis

How can we calculate the derivative of a rotating unit vector in a coordinate free way? That is, we want to compute the derivative -with respect to time- of a vector function $\vec{\varepsilon}: [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$, whose length is kept constant and equal to one $|\vec{\varepsilon}(t)|=1$ for any $t \in [0, +\infty)$.

(Such computations are frequently useful in physics, especially in kinematics, when calculating velocities, accelerations etc, especially in many-body problems where the use of a single coordinate system might prove disfunctional).

Below, one answer is posted but it would be nice to see other approaches as well.

Comment: I’m unclear as to what you’re looking for here. First of all, it appears from your own answer that you really want to work in $\mathbb R^3$. Is the plane of motion known ahead of time? It’s a basic fact of differential calculus that for a differentiable curve given by a function $\gamma: I\to\mathbb R^n$ with $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ an interval, the vector $\gamma'(t)=\operatorname{d}\gamma_t(1)$ is tangent to $\gamma$ at $t$ and if you parametrize by arc length, $\gamma'(s)$ is a unit vector and $(\gamma\circ s)'(t)=\gamma'(s)s'(t)$, i.e., the unit tangent multiplied by the speed.

Comment: ... Doing very much beyond this requires making some assumptions about the coordinate system and other structures in play. For instance, the idea of angle that you use in your answer is intimately connected to the inner product.

Comment: The derivative is calculated at a specific point in time $t\in[0,+\infty)$. Thus it is an instant quantity. This allows us to consider an infinitesimal time interval $dt$, during which the plane of rotation is considered (instantly) constant and it is this plane where the infinitesimal arc $d\phi$ lies on.  $\vec{\epsilon}$ and $\vec{\eta}$ define this instant plane of rotation. However, generally, for an arbitrary time interval, the rotation is considered in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (in this sense, we could have  written $\vec{\varepsilon}: [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ for the function).

Comment: If you look even more closely, there’s no rotation at all—the motion is linear. That’s pretty much the point of the differential calculus. Be that as it may, that’s not at all what you’ve got in your question. It also seems that you’re introducing a circularity in the reasoning: the “plane of motion” is *defined* by $\dot{\vec\epsilon}$ and $\ddot{\vec\epsilon}$, so you need to have those first in order to talk sensibly about it.

Comment: @amd: thank you for your remarks. I feel what we are discussing here underlies the foundations of classical mechanics. It can all be described in various level of abstraction. I think the most elegant description can be given in terms of the manifold (phase space) its tangent bundle (where velocities "live") and its cotangent bundle (where accelerations "live"). Here I provided an answer targeted mostly at the introductory undergaduate level for a student of physics, mechanics or mathematics. It would be nice to see other desriptions as well. This is one of the reasons for this post.

Comment: I’m trying to see if we can sharpen your question so as to increase the chances of getting any of those other descriptions that you’re hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

We will use $t$ to denote the independent variable since it normally stands for time.
Thus, at any given instant $t$, the value of the function will be a  unit vector $\vec{\varepsilon}(t)$. 
We will apply the definition of the derivative, so we need to compute the vector
\begin{equation} \label{def1}
\frac{d}{dt}\vec{\varepsilon}(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\vec{\varepsilon}(t + \Delta t) - \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}
   First note that since $|\vec{\varepsilon}(t)|^{2} = \vec{\varepsilon}(t) \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}(t) = 1$ by differentiating both sides we get
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{d}{dt} \big( \vec{\varepsilon}(t) \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}(t) \big) = \frac{d \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{dt} \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}(t) + \vec{\varepsilon}(t) \cdot \frac{d \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{dt} = \\
    \\
2 \frac{d \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{dt} \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}(t) = 0 \Leftrightarrow 2 \frac{d \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{dt} \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}(t) = 0
\end{array}
$$
   Thus $\frac{d \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{dt} \cdot \vec{\varepsilon}(t) = 0$ which is equivalent to the fact that $\vec{\varepsilon}(t)$ and its derivative vector $\frac{d \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{dt}$ are perpendicular
\begin{equation} \label{def2}
\vec{\varepsilon}(t) \bot \frac{d \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{dt}
\end{equation}
The situation can be presented in the following picture:
[image]
$\Delta s$ is the length of the arc spanned by the edge of the unit vector $\vec{\varepsilon}(t)$ while it rotates by an angle of $\Delta \varphi$ during time $\Delta t$. Since $\varphi$   is measured in radians we have $\Delta s = \Delta \varphi  |\vec{\varepsilon}(t)|$ which implies that
$$
\Delta s = \Delta \varphi
$$
Notice that (in the figure) we also have:  $|\vec{\eta}(t)|=1$ and $ \ \vec{\eta}(t) \bot \vec{\varepsilon}(t)$.
Now, during that time interval $\Delta t$ the vector has changed by
$$
\Delta \vec{\varepsilon} = \vec{\varepsilon}(t + \Delta t) - \vec{\varepsilon}(t)
$$
While $\Delta t \rightarrow 0 $ (the notation $dt \rightarrow 0$ will be used instead from now on) we can notice two things: i). the direction of the vector $d \vec{\varepsilon}  = \vec{\varepsilon}(t + dt) - \vec{\varepsilon}(t)$ "tends" to become perpendicular to $\vec{\varepsilon}(t)$ and thus parallel to the direction specified by $\vec{\eta}(t)$ and ii). the length of the vector $d \vec{\varepsilon}$ "tends" to become equal to the length of the arc $ds$ thus
\begin{equation}  \label{def3}
|d \vec{\varepsilon}| = |\vec{\varepsilon}(t + dt) - \vec{\varepsilon}(t)| = ds = d \varphi
\end{equation}
(where $d \varphi$ is measured in radians).
   Now, combining the above, and substituting in $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{\varepsilon}(t)$ we get
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{d}{dt}\vec{\varepsilon}(t) = \lim_{dt \rightarrow 0} \frac{\vec{\varepsilon}(t + dt) - \vec{\varepsilon}(t)}{dt} = \lim_{dt \rightarrow 0} \frac{d \varepsilon}{dt} = \frac{d \varphi}{dt} \vec{\eta}(t)
\end{array}
$$
   Finally, if we define a vector $\vec{\omega}$ with direction perpendicular to the plane defined by $(\vec{\varepsilon}(t), \vec{\eta}(t))$ and with length $|\vec{\omega}|=\frac{d \varphi}{dt}$ then we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\vec{\varepsilon}(t) = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{\varepsilon}(t) =  \frac{d \varphi}{dt} \vec{\eta}(t)
$$

Comment: In order to use the cross product, you’ve moved from the $\mathbb R^2$ of the problem to $\mathbb R^3$. I suppose that’s a good thing, since if you stayed strictly in $\mathbb R^2$, you wouldn’t be able to find a non-zero vector $\vec\omega$ that’s orthogonal to both $\vec\epsilon$ and $\dot{\vec\epsilon}$.

Comment: In other words, $\vec\epsilon(t)$ is normal to the unit circle, so it is by definition orthogonal to the always-tangent $\dot{\vec\epsilon}(t)$. The final equation basically says that, in polar (cylindrical) coordinates chosen to coincide with the plane of motion, $\dot{\vec\epsilon}(t)=\omega(t)\vec\theta$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity and $\vec\theta$ is the polar basis vector.

Comment: Your definition of $\vec\omega$ is ambiguous: one possible choice will result in $\dot{\vec\epsilon}$ having the wrong direction.

Comment: I (implicitly) defined $\vec\omega$ (see the figure) so as to coincide with the direction of the vector poduct $\vec\epsilon\times\dot{\vec{\epsilon}}$

Comment: You should make that explicit.